# Creating variables in MySQL Triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Please have a look at the below SQL Query.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Portfolio_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Portfolio` FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO Initial_Fees (idPortfolio, Current_Time_Stamp, Initial_Gross_Fee, Initial_Monetary_Fee)
VALUES (
New.idPortfolio, 
current_timestamp,
(New.Invest_Amount*(New.Initial_Gross_Fee/100)),
(New.Invest_Amount*(New.Initial_Gross_Fee/100))*(New.Initial_Company_Fee/100)
)
```

In here, the `Initial_Monetary_Fee = Initial_Gross_Fee * (New.Initial_Company_Fee/100)`

But I have written it `(New.Invest_Amount*(New.Initial_Gross_Fee/100))*(New.Initial_Company_Fee/100)`

Instead of that, I would like to create variables and assign the values to them, so I can avoid such long calculations. For an example, something like below.

```
InitialGrossFee = (New.Invest_Amount*(New.Initial_Gross_Fee/100))
IntialMonetaryFee  = InitialGrossFee * (New.Initial_Company_Fee/100)
```

So, how can I create such variables and store values in side MySQL triggers? I prefer to have some explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiple statements within in a trigger you must use BEGIN .... END.
Then you can assign values to uservars as usual:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Portfolio_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Portfolio`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @grossfee := New.Invest_Amount*(New.Initial_Gross_Fee/100);
    INSERT INTO Initial_Fees (idPortfolio, Current_Time_Stamp, Initial_Gross_Fee, Initial_Monetary_Fee)
    VALUES (
        New.idPortfolio, 
        current_timestamp,
        @grossfee,
        @grossfee *(New.Initial_Company_Fee/100)
        );
END$$
```